# add scroll bar if trackpad not available

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using javascript, I attached an event that is triggered when the user is hovering (on `mouseover`) over `"col-1 blue"` below, which is in the middle of two divs and runs vertically down the page (You can see what it looks like here https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/0r69mjh7/16/) but on my real application the vertical height is dynamic and always much longer/taller.

On a mac, with a trackpad, I can scroll down the center of the page over this blue bar and keep the hover property activated, which is very important for this particular application. As far as I'm aware, this type of functionality is not available on most other computers. Question: Is there a way to put a scroll bar if (and only if) this trackpad type scrolling is not available.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("col-1 blue");
x.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  console.log("do something while hovering over blue...");
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
/*-- our cleafix hack -- */

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 16.66%;
  /*-- our gutter -- */
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #FFDCDC;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 260px;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 100%;
}

.outline,
.outline * {
  outline: 1px solid #F6A1A1;
}
/*-- some extra column content styling --*/

[class*='col-'] > p {
  background-color: #FFC2C2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.col-1.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="red" class="col-2">
      hi
      <br/> hi
      <br/> hi
      <br/>

    </div>
    <div class="col-1 blue">
      d
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      hi
      <br/> hi
      <br/> hi
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add some JS to that fiddle, and increase the height of the cols?

Comment: The fiddle was just to help you visualize the layout (i.e. the column in the middle is where I'm hoving), but to help you further I made the columns taller, and added some js just to illustrate that something is supposed to happen while the mouseover event is active and that, on a mac, for example, one can scroll down (with the trackpad) and keep the mouseover active https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/0r69mjh7/37/

Comment: So I just tried it out on my PC(Windows), and I can scroll down with my mouse wheel while staying hovered on the blue box. What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: thank you for checking (I don't have a windows) I had heard that functionality was only available on mac